# How to read only part of input

Tags: php

I am trying to figure out how to read only couple of lines needed for the database from a eve-online kill mail:

> 2011.12.30 23:26
>
> Victim: Annabel Lust
>   Corp: Shadow Monolith
>   Alliance: Shadow of xXDEATHXx
>   Faction: None
>   Destroyed: Cheetah
>   System: C6CG-W
>   Security: 0.0
>   Damage Taken: 827
>
> Involved parties:
>
> Name: Milena Dush
>   Security: 0.6
>   Corp: nXo
>   Alliance: Intrepid Crossing
>   Faction: None
>   Ship: Hound
>   Weapon: Caldari Navy Bane Torpedo
>   Damage Done: 457
>
> Destroyed items:
>
> Sisters Expanded Probe Launcher
>   Catalyzed Cold-Gas Arcjet Thrusters
>   Nanofiber Internal Structure II
>   Overdrive Injector System II
>   Hardwiring - Genolution Core Augmentation CA-2 (Cargo)
>   Nanite Engineering (Cargo)
>   Sisters Core Scanner Probe, Qty: 5 (Cargo)
>   Micro Auxiliary Power Core I (Cargo)
>   Sisters Deep Space Scanner Probe, Qty: 5 (Cargo)
>
> Dropped items:
>
> Covert Ops Cloaking Device II
>   Sisters Combat Scanner Probe, Qty: 5
>   Warp Disruptor II
>   Nanofiber Internal Structure II
>   Astrometric Pinpointing (Cargo)
>   Small Gravity Capacitor Upgrade I, Qty: 2 (Cargo)
>   Salvager I (Cargo)
>   Interceptors (Cargo)
>   Thermodynamics (Cargo)
>   Co-Processor I (Cargo)

When a user inputs the killmail into a multi-textbox I only need to read the destroyed items and dropped items and have the quantity in a separate string.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Regex, plain and simple.

Comment: Do the items without a quantity mean the quantity is 1?

Comment: [Here's a start](http://codepad.viper-7.com/7SNbmH).

Answer (score 0):

You can use explode(separator, text) to split the text in two and array.
Example:
$str=explode(":","YourText");

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$str = "    2011.12.30 23:26

    Victim: Annabel Lust
    Corp: Shadow Monolith
    Alliance: Shadow of xXDEATHXx
    Faction: None
    Destroyed: Cheetah
    System: C6CG-W
    Security: 0.0
    Damage Taken: 827

    Involved parties:

    Name: Milena Dush
    Security: 0.6
    Corp: nXo
    Alliance: Intrepid Crossing
    Faction: None
    Ship: Hound
    Weapon: Caldari Navy Bane Torpedo
    Damage Done: 457

    Destroyed items:

    Sisters Expanded Probe Launcher
    Catalyzed Cold-Gas Arcjet Thrusters
    Nanofiber Internal Structure II
    Overdrive Injector System II
    Hardwiring - Genolution Core Augmentation CA-2 (Cargo)
    Nanite Engineering (Cargo)
    Sisters Core Scanner Probe, Qty: 5 (Cargo)
    Micro Auxiliary Power Core I (Cargo)
    Sisters Deep Space Scanner Probe, Qty: 5 (Cargo)

    Dropped items:

    Covert Ops Cloaking Device II
    Sisters Combat Scanner Probe, Qty: 5
    Warp Disruptor II
    Nanofiber Internal Structure II
    Astrometric Pinpointing (Cargo)
    Small Gravity Capacitor Upgrade I, Qty: 2 (Cargo)
    Salvager I (Cargo)
    Interceptors (Cargo)
    Thermodynamics (Cargo)
    Co-Processor I (Cargo)
";

var_dump(parseItems('/Destroyed items:(?P<destroyedItems>.*)Dropped items:/is', $str, 1));
var_dump(parseItems('/Dropped items:(?P<droppedItems>.*)/is', $str, 1));
function parseItems($regex, $str, $defaultQty = 0){
    preg_match($regex, $str, $match);
    $lines = explode("\n", $match[1]);
    $defaultQty = 0;
    $items = array();
    foreach($lines as $key => $line){
        $line = trim($line);
        if($line != ""){
            $quantity = (strpos($line, "Qty:") != false) ? getQty($line) : $defaultQty;
            $items[] = array($line => $quantity);
        }
    }
    return $items;
}

function getQty($line){
    preg_match('/, Qty:\s+(?P<quantity>[0-9]+)/', $line, $match);
    return $match['quantity'];
}
```

This should give you an array of dropped and destroyed lines along with its quantity. It returns associative array, where key is the line and value is the quantity.

Comment: Read the question, not just the title.

Comment: yeah that aint helping me since the kill mail vary from length ;)

Comment: Sorry, I should have read the question right..
@Crash2k,I am not sure what is kill mail, does it have specific format like the one above?